# JCalendar and PropertyChangeListener: event is not fired for current day

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I'm using `JCalendar` and have setup a listener using a `PropertyChangeListener`. My problem is that this listener will not respond to an event on the current day, I assume because there is no change in the property. I want it to be able to respond to selecting today's date, as the calendar leads to a diary. When opened I still want the calendar to open on "today's" date, but to have a listener that will respond to pressing "today's" date. My code for the listener is below:

```
final JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();

calendar.getDayChooser().addPropertyChangeListener("day", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {

        if(Calendar.AddJob!=1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Entry Found");
            frame.dispose();
            String date = EditDate(calendar.getDate().toString());
            WorkDiary.WorkDiaryGui(date);
        }

        if(Calendar.AddJob==1){
            String date = EditDate(calendar.getDate().toString());  
            Calendar.AddJob=0;
            frame.dispose();
            WorkDiaryAddJob.WorkDiaryAddJobGui(CalReg, date);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My problem is that this listener will not respond to an event on the current day, I assume because there is no change in the property.*

Your assumption is correct: day chooser doesn't fire a day property change if you press the button for the very selected day (i.e. today). And it makes sense because the property doesn't change, actually.

> *I want it to be able to respond to selecting today's date, as the calendar leads to a diary.*

To modify the aforementioned behavior we can use [setAlwaysFireDayProperty(boolean alwaysFire)](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDayChooser.html#setAlwaysFireDayProperty%28boolean%29) method to force day chooser to always fire a property change event:

```
JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();        
JDayChooser dayChooser = calendar.getDayChooser();
dayChooser.setAlwaysFireDayProperty(true); // here is the key
dayChooser.addPropertyChangeListener("day", ...);
```

Note: This is also explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339730/1795530).

Comment: you are great. This is what I try to find

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to add an ActionListener instead of PropertyChangeListener...

see http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDayChooser.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29:

it says: "JDayChooser is the ActionListener for all day buttons" (on ActionListener)

```
 calendar.getDayChooser().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     ...
 };
```